# Remove spacing/padding between <TD> with images in them, in OUTLOOK 2007

Tags: html, css, padding, outlook-2007, spacing

I'm going absolutely crazy. I have a table, which I've simplified down to two adjacent cells with one image each (the images are part of a larger picture, so there can be NO spacing between them). I'm getting some spacing or padding between the table cells, just on the left and right, not the top or bottom. I've tried everything I can find on forums, both inline html as well as inline CSS styling, including:

```
cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0"
border="0"
align="left"

display: block;
display: inline-block;
display: inline-table;
border-collapse: collapse; 
border:none;
mso-table-lspace:0;
mso-table-rspace:0;
width:403px!important;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
```

No combination of any of these attributes seem to work. Here is my code if you want to take a look (remember, this is a reduced version). It works perfectly fine in my browser, but when I paste it into Outlook I get spacing before, between and after each cell. I have created a magenta background so I can see the spacing clearly.

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="
border:none;
border-collapse:collapse;
background-color:magenta;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:15px;
color:#4A4A4A;
width:403px!important;
mso-table-lspace:0;
mso-table-rspace:0;
">
    <tr>
        <td width="211">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cms_assets/accounts/3ceae742-b87e-4bdc-a6b3-2bcfc1c5c2d7/site-30100/cms-assets/images/457997.seal-bar-gold.png" width="211"/>
        </td>
        <td width="192">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cms_assets/accounts/3ceae742-b87e-4bdc-a6b3-2bcfc1c5c2d7/site-30100/cms-assets/images/569397.seal-bar-silver.png" width="192"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You should make a fiddle.

Comment: It seems that the second image has some transparent pixels on the right side. This could cause apparent spacing issues. [Demonstration here](http://jsfiddle.net/q1ourw0q/).

Comment: Maybe Outlook has rendering rules that won't allow what you're doing? http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

Comment: There may be one pixel line at the far right, but since that is part of the original image, it is included in the image size and the table should wrap neatly around that. I'm mostly concerned about the spacing between the pictures/table cells, as well as to the left of the first image (because that connects to another image in the final version). I'll work on making a fiddle, although I've never done it before and I'm not sure if it will display my problem since it only comes up in Outlook (not in browsers).

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the problem I'm having: [Screenshot](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cms_assets/accounts/3ceae742-b87e-4bdc-a6b3-2bcfc1c5c2d7/site-30100/cms-assets/images/131273.spacing-example.png)

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` it is inline tag, by default, therefore we have space under it. You can set `font-size: 0px;` for parent to prevent empty space, or set `display: block;` to `<img>` (my choice).
[My solution](http://codepen.io/PredokMiF/pen/aJddyE) and [article about this behaviour](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)